# Problem with selectInput Inside a renderUI command. when I select a choice, the code runs normally but then it gives me again the original choices

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, selectinput, renderui

Hi I would appreciate your help.
I have the attached code. I import an excel data file and read the data. I have a renderUi command which by selectInput, reads the names of the inserted table and plots the relative columns of the data table.

When I run the code and I select the  ParameterName_time and ParameterName ( which are the x and y parts of the plot ) , I can see the plot for just half a second but then it dissapears and the choices are back in the original state.

It looks like it is working but can not store the result.
Maybe I need to use the updateselectInput command or it is something with the reactivity of hte inputs or the plot. please help !

```
# Define server function  
server <- function(input,output,session) {[enter image description here][1]
 
  
 
  
 
  Excel <- reactive({                                   #  DATA IMPORT  ------------------------------------------
    inFile <- input$Excel
    if (is.null(inFile)) { return(NULL) }    
    dataFile <- read_excel(inFile$datapath,sheet=1)
    return(dataFile)
  })
  RV <- reactiveValues(Excel = data.frame())
  
  
  
  output$Table_Of_Data = DT::renderDataTable({     #  DATA TABLE ------------------------------------------
    
    RV$Excel<-Excel()
    
  },options = list(scrollX = TRUE)) 
  
#  if (input$submitbutton_Show_Table>0){             
#  }
    output$summary <- renderPrint({                #  Summary of DATA TABLE ------------------------------------------
      dataset <- Excel()
      summary(dataset)
    })
    
 
    
  #  RValsl <- reactive(input$NumberOfDates_L  )
 #   RValsr<- reactive(input$NumberOfDates_R  )
    
    
 
   
      
      
        output$timeDataSetNumber <- renderUI({
          fluidRow(
        numericInput(inputId = "NumberOfDates_L",                      # INPUT PARAMETER
                     label = "Number Of Different Time Data Sets (Left Side):",
                     value = 1 ,
                     min = 1,
        ),
        numericInput(inputId = "NumberOfDates_R",                      # INPUT PARAMETER
                     label = "Number Of Different Time Data Sets (Right Side):",
                     value = 1 ,
                     min = 1,
          )
        
          )
        })
        
         
        output$Plotoutput <- renderPlot({
        
        
        
     
        n<-input$NumberOfDates_L
        output$tabsets <- renderUI({
          
          Panels <- lapply(1:n, function(number){
            tabPanel(paste0("Set #", number),
                     fluidRow(
                       selectInput("ParameterName_time","Select the Date vector for this entry",names(RV$Excel),multiple = TRUE ),
                       selectInput("ParameterName", "Select the KPIs for this entry:",   names(RV$Excel) ,multiple = TRUE ), 
                     ),
                     
            )
            
          })
          
          do.call(tabsetPanel,Panels)
        })
    #============
    k<-input$NumberOfDates_R
    
    output$tabsets_R <- renderUI({
      
      Panels_R <- lapply(1:k, function(number){
        tabPanel(paste0("Set #", number),
                 fluidRow(
                   selectInput("ParameterName_time_R","Select the Date vector for this entry",names(RV$Excel)),
                   selectInput("ParameterName_R", "Select the KPIs for this entry:",names(RV$Excel),multiple = TRUE), 
                 ),
                 
        )
        
      })
      
      do.call(tabsetPanel,Panels_R)
    })
     
      
    
   Excel<-RV$Excel ##########################################################
   ###############################
   ###################################################
 
 
   
   
     
   # if (input$submitbutton>0){
    
    source(file = "path................TimeVector.R")
    TVmean=TimeVector(input$Starting_Date,input$Ending_Date,input$Time)[,1]
   
    TV1=TimeVector(input$Starting_Date,input$Ending_Date,input$Time)[,2]
    TV2=TimeVector(input$Starting_Date,input$Ending_Date,input$Time)[,3]
    
    #====================================================
   # Value<- Excel %>% select(c(input$ParameterName))

    source(file = "C:/Users/AntoniosTriantos/OneDrive - ClearWELL Oilfield Solutions/Desktop/App/Scripts/ReducedParameter.R")
   
    
    # Left Side of the plot 
    kpi_entries=length(input$ParameterName) 
  #  kpi_Time_entries=length(input$ParameterName_time)
    
    KPITable=c(TVmean)
    for ( i in 1:kpi_entries){
    #  for ( j in 1:kpi_Time_entries){
    AV_Prop_Value_reduced=ReducedParameter(input$ParameterName_time[1],input$ParameterName[i],Excel,TV1,TV2) 
    KPITable=(cbind.data.frame(KPITable,AV_Prop_Value_reduced ))
      }
 #   }
    
    
    
    # Right Side of the plot 
    if (length(input$ParameterName_R)>0){
    kpi_entries_R=length(input$ParameterName_R)
    KPITable_R=c(TVmean)
    for ( i in 1:kpi_entries_R){
      AV_Prop_Value_reduced_R=ReducedParameter(input$ParameterName_time_R[1],input$ParameterName_R[i],Excel,TV1,TV2) 
      KPITable_R=(cbind.data.frame(KPITable_R,AV_Prop_Value_reduced_R ))
    }
    }
  
    #====================================================
    
      
    source(file = "path................Plot.R")
    
   
     Plot<-PlotFunction(TVmean,AV_Prop_Value_reduced,kpi_entries,KPITable,input$ParameterName_R,kpi_entries_R,KPITable_R)   
   
    
 #   }
    }) 
   

 
} 











ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                navbarPage(
                  # theme = "cerulean",  # <--- To use a theme, uncomment this
                  "ClearKPI",
                  tabPanel("Navbar 1",
                           
                           sidebarPanel(wellPanel(fileInput('Excel', 'Choose XLSX File',
                                                            accept=c('sheetName', 'header'), multiple=FALSE))),
                           
                           
                           
                           
                           
                        #  actionButton("submitbutton_Show_Table","Show table",class ="btn btn-primary"),
                           h1("Excel Data"),
                           DT::dataTableOutput("Table_Of_Data"),                    # SHOW DATA TABLE 
                          
                           
                           # Output: Verbatim text for data summary ----
                           verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
                           
   
                           
                           
                           
                           
                           headerPanel("KPI Entry Point") ,                    # INPUT KPIs vs Dates PARAMETER
                             uiOutput("timeDataSetNumber") ,
                           
                               mainPanel(h2("Left side of the plot - Input:"),
                                   uiOutput("tabsets")),
                                 
                                              
                                mainPanel(h2("Right side of the plot - Input:"),
                                    uiOutput("tabsets_R")),
                           
                          
                           
                           
                           
                 
                           
                          headerPanel("Edit Plot") ,                    # INPUT KPIs vs Dates PARAMETER
                             numericInput(inputId = "Time",                      # INPUT PARAMETER
                                          label = "Number of Hours to round:",
                                          value = 4),
                             
                             
                             
                             dateInput(
                               inputId="Starting_Date" ,
                               label="Starting Date:",
                               value = "2022-02-08",
                               min = NULL,
                               max = NULL,
                               format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                               startview = "year",
                               weekstart = 0,
                               language = "en",
                               width = NULL,
                               autoclose = TRUE,
                               datesdisabled = NULL,
                               daysofweekdisabled = NULL),
                             
                             dateInput(                                          # INPUT PARAMETER
                               inputId="Ending_Date" ,
                               label="Ending Date:",
                               value = "2022-06-27",
                               min = NULL,
                               max = NULL,
                               format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                               startview = "year",
                               weekstart = 0,
                               language = "en",
                               width = NULL,
                               autoclose = TRUE,
                               datesdisabled = NULL,
                               daysofweekdisabled = NULL),
                           
                          
                  #      actionButton("submitbutton","Submit",class ="btn btn-primary"),
                         mainPanel(h2("Plot:"),
                              plotOutput(outputId = "Plotoutput",  width = 1250 ,  height = 800)                 # OUTPUT PARAMETER
                           ), # mainPanel
                           
                           
                  ) 
                  
)
)



rm(list = ls())
source(file = "path................UI.R")

source(file = "path................SERVER.R")



# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If you want someone to help you, please consider posting a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In the above code you are sourcing many external programs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
You need to introduce the actionbuttons to stop the procedure for being reactive and then you need to introduce both selectInpout and UpdateSelectInput commands.

```
# Define server function  
server <- function(input,output,session) {
 
  
 
  
 
  Excel <- reactive({                                   #  DATA IMPORT  ------------------------------------------
    inFile <- input$Excel
    if (is.null(inFile)) { return(NULL) }    
    dataFile <- read_excel(inFile$datapath,sheet=1)
    return(dataFile)
  })
  RV <- reactiveValues(Excel = data.frame())
  
  
  
  output$Table_Of_Data = DT::renderDataTable({     #  DATA TABLE ------------------------------------------
    if((input$submitbutton_Show_Table %% 2) == 0){
    RV$Excel<-Excel()
    }
  },options = list(dom='Bfrtip',buttons=list('copy','pdf','csv','excel','print')) , extensions='Buttons') 
  
#  if (input$submitbutton_Show_Table>0){             
#  }
    output$summary <- renderPrint({                #  Summary of DATA TABLE ------------------------------------------
      if((input$submitbutton_Summary %% 2) == 0){
      dataset <- Excel()
      summary(dataset)
      }
    })
    
 
    output$Plotoutput <- renderPlot({
      
      Excel<-isolate(RV$Excel )
   #==================
         
      RValsl <-  (input$NumberOfDates_L  )
      RValsr<-  (input$NumberOfDates_R  )
      
      
      
  
      
      output$timeDataSetNumber <- renderUI({
        fluidRow(
          numericInput(inputId = "NumberOfDates_L",                      # INPUT PARAMETER
                       label = "Number Of Different Time Data Sets (Left Side):",
                       value = RValsl()) ,
          
          numericInput(inputId = "NumberOfDates_R",                      # INPUT PARAMETER
                       label = "Number Of Different Time Data Sets (Right Side):",
                       value = RValsr()) 
        )
      })
        
 #===========================
        
      if ((input$submitbuttonENTERKPIS %% 2) == 0) {
        
        n<-input$NumberOfDates_L
        
        output$tabsets <- renderUI({
          
          Panels <- lapply(1:n, function(number){
            tabPanel(paste0("Set #", number),
                     fluidRow(
                       selectInput("ParameterName_time","Select the Date vector for this entry",names(RV$Excel)  ),
                       selectInput("ParameterName", "Select the KPIs for this entry:",   names(RV$Excel) ,multiple = TRUE ), 
                     ),
                     
            )
            
          })
          updateSelectInput(session, "ParameterName_time",
                            label ="Select the Date vector for this entry" ,
                            choices = names(RV$Excel) )
          
          updateSelectInput(session, "ParameterName",
                            label ="Select the KPIs for this entry:" ,
                            choices = names(RV$Excel) )
          
          do.call(tabsetPanel,Panels)
        })
    #============
    k<-input$NumberOfDates_R
    
    output$tabsets_R <- renderUI({
      
      Panels_R <- lapply(1:k, function(number){
        tabPanel(paste0("Set #", number),
                 fluidRow(
                   selectInput("ParameterName_time_R","Select the Date vector for this entry",names(RV$Excel)),
                   selectInput("ParameterName_R", "Select the KPIs for this entry:",names(RV$Excel),multiple = TRUE), 
                 ),
                 
        )
        
      })
      
      updateSelectInput(session, "ParameterName_time_R",
                        label ="Select the Date vector for this entry" ,
                        choices = names(RV$Excel) )
      
      updateSelectInput(session, "ParameterName_R",
                        label ="Select the KPIs for this entry:" ,
                        choices = names(RV$Excel) )
      
      do.call(tabsetPanel,Panels_R)
    })
    
    
     
      
      
}
                       
    
  # Excel<-RV$Excel ##########################################################
   ###############################
   ###################################################
 
  
   
   if ((input$submitbutton %% 2) == 0) {
   
    
    source(file = "C:/Users/AntoniosTriantos/OneDrive - ClearWELL Oilfield Solutions/Desktop/App/Scripts/TimeVector.R")
    TVmean=TimeVector(input$Starting_Date,input$Ending_Date,input$Time)[,1]
   
    TV1=TimeVector(input$Starting_Date,input$Ending_Date,input$Time)[,2]
    TV2=TimeVector(input$Starting_Date,input$Ending_Date,input$Time)[,3]
    
    #====================================================
   # Value<- Excel %>% select(c(input$ParameterName))

    source(file = "C:/Users/AntoniosTriantos/OneDrive - ClearWELL Oilfield Solutions/Desktop/App/Scripts/ReducedParameter.R")
   
    
    # Left Side of the plot 
    kpi_entries=length(input$ParameterName) 
  #  kpi_Time_entries=length(input$ParameterName_time)
    
    KPITable=c(TVmean)
    for ( i in 1:kpi_entries){
    #  for ( j in 1:kpi_Time_entries){
    AV_Prop_Value_reduced=ReducedParameter(input$ParameterName_time[1],input$ParameterName[i],Excel,TV1,TV2) 
    KPITable=(cbind.data.frame(KPITable,AV_Prop_Value_reduced ))
      }
 #   }
    
    
    
    # Right Side of the plot 
    if (length(input$ParameterName_R)>0){
    kpi_entries_R=length(input$ParameterName_R)
    KPITable_R=c(TVmean)
    for ( i in 1:kpi_entries_R){
      AV_Prop_Value_reduced_R=ReducedParameter(input$ParameterName_time_R[1],input$ParameterName_R[i],Excel,TV1,TV2) 
      KPITable_R=(cbind.data.frame(KPITable_R,AV_Prop_Value_reduced_R ))
    }
    }
  
    #====================================================
    
      
    source(file = "C:/Users/AntoniosTriantos/OneDrive - ClearWELL Oilfield Solutions/Desktop/App/Scripts/Plot.R")
 
     Plot<-PlotFunction(TVmean,AV_Prop_Value_reduced,kpi_entries,KPITable,input$ParameterName_R,kpi_entries_R,KPITable_R)   
     

    
    }
      

    }) 
    

}
```